# Check security header in Mule http:listener

Tags: security, http, mule

I have a need to check some security HTTP header (called for example X-MyApp-Security) value before processing it after Mule http:listener. Header should be checked like basic auth header but more simply.

I found some [Mule documentation](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Security+Manager+Configuration+Reference) about this but don't understand how to use it my simple flow:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="${httpServer.host}" port="${httpServer.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<flow name="planadoWebhookFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST"/>
    <set-payload value="Hello from security area!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Please help me with header authentication in Mule 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "http:basic-security-filter" element, here you have an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
      xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp"
      xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
      xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
      xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
      xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
      xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws"
      xmlns:smtps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps"
      xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
      xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"      
      xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
      xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps/current/mule-smtps.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.1/mule-spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <spring:beans>      
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
              <ss:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
              <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON" />
            </ss:user-service>
          </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>    
    <flow name="testingFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="Before Authentication" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Failure"/>
        <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        <logger message="After Authentication" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Failure"/>

    </flow>


</mule>
```

You can find more information in the next link:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector#authentication

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I have updated the answer. I wish it could be more useful.